# Javascript and PHP to fill WordPress form element

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I am using WordPress and want to take the email from a registered user's account to auto-fill a form.

I'm using two plugins: Snippets for the PHP code and Scripts n Styles for the JavaScript.

The PHP code is

```
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user();
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var useremail = <?php echo json_encode($user_email) ?> ;
</script>
```

and the Javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () 
document.getElementsByName("element_name")[0].value = useremail;
}
</script>
```

However nothing is being filled into the element.

Does anyone have any experience using PHP and JavaScript to auto-populate a form element?

I believe the issue is with the PHP code since I can insert a value into the form using the JavaScript if I put the value I want in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First line in your php should be:

```
<?php $current_user =  wp_get_current_user();
```

and:

```
<?php echo $user_email ; ?>
```

In js, you're missing an open brace {

```
window.onload = function () {
```